# Why don't you have to use the new keyword to create objects?

Tags: c++, new-operator

This is a really simple question but I havn't done c++ properly for years and so I'm a little baffled by this. Also, it's not the easiest thing (for me at least) to look up on the internet, not for trying.

Why doesn't this use the `new` keyword and how does it work?

Basically, what's going on here?

```
CPlayer newPlayer = CPlayer(position, attacker);
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This expression:

```
CPlayer(position, attacker)
```

creates a temporary object of type `CPlayer` using the above constructor, then:

```
CPlayer newPlayer =...;
```

The mentioned temporary object gets copied using the copy constructor to `newPlayer`. A better way is to write the following to avoid temporaries:

```
CPlayer newPlayer(position, attacker);
```

Comment: Actually compiler will probably optimize it. In that case copy constructor will not get called.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case

Comment: An assignment in a declaration isn't any less efficient than using the constructor syntax.  If they had been separate statements, than the remark about temporaries would be correct.  The essence is that this declares a CPlayer (typically on the stack) rather than allocating space for it from the free store (heap).

Comment: GCC is not calling the copy constructor, whether or not I have optimizations turned on.

Comment: They say that in g++, you can disable this optimization with the option -fno-elide-constructors.
I have not checked.

Comment: If this creates an object on the stack can it live past the function it was created in's scope?

Comment: No, almost by definition: Objects on the stack only live while they are in scope. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+stack+heap

Comment: I don't think this answer is precisely correct.  The OP's code *looks* like it makes a temporary and then copies it, but the standard 12.1.11 suggests otherwise.  It's just a normal constructor call, which jleedev discovered.

Comment: It's up to the compiler whether to elide copies or not (in the situations where it's permitted). 12.8/15.

Comment: I like the way of `CPlayer newPlayer(position, attacker);` since this style keeps the C++ code style same as C when creating stack variable. Using `CPlayer newPlayer = CPlayer(position, attacker);` is unnecessary and can be confusing.

Answer (score 71):

The above constructs a CPlayer object on the stack, hence it doesn't need `new`. You only need to use `new` if you are trying to allocate a CPlayer object on the heap. If you're using heap allocation, the code would look like this:

```
CPlayer *newPlayer = new CPlayer(position, attacker);
```

Notice that in this case we're using a pointer to a CPlayer object that will need to be cleaned up by a matching call to `delete`. An object allocated on the stack will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.

Actually it would have been easier and more obvious to write:

```
CPlayer newPlayer(position, attacker);
```

A lot of compilers will optimise the version you posted to the above anyway and it's clearer to read.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: "An object allocated on the heap will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope."

Comment: You're correct, I meant to write "stack", not "heap". Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Agree on this. We should keep C++ code the same style as C code. So `CPlayer newPlayer(position, attacker);` is better than `CPlayer newPlayer = CPlayer(position, attacker);` if you want to create a stack variable.

Answer (score 12):

```
CPlayer newPlayer = CPlayer(position, attacker);
```

This line creates a new local object of type CPlayer.  Despite its function-like appearance, this simply calls CPlayer's constructor.  No temporaries or copying are involved.  The object named newPlayer lives as long as the scope it's enclosed in.  You don't use the `new` keyword here because C++ isn't Java.

```
CPlayer* newPlayer = new CPlayer(position, attacker);
```

This line constructs a CPlayer object on the heap and defines a pointer named newPlayer to point at it.  The object lives until someone `delete`s it.

Comment: "No temporaries or copying are involved" -- This is not exactly true. There is no such guarantee. But every decent compiler should elide the copy.

Comment: (Re)learning C++ now after over a decade of .NET development. I had a C++ in college about 20 years or so ago but haven't touched it since.

Would the reason for making a heap-allocated reference be for like a class-level variable that you might access in various functions or other classes? Is there a point to making a heap-allocated variable instead of a stack-allocated one where it will only be used in a single function?

Comment: @clamum That’s a separate question with lots of answers already on SO.  Here’s one good one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500497/46821

Answer (score 7):

newPlayer is no dynamically allocated variable but an auto, stack-allocated variable:

```
CPlayer* newPlayer = new CPlayer(pos, attacker);
```

is different from

```
CPlayer newPlayer = CPlayer(pos, attacker);
```

newPlayer is allocated on the stack via the normal CPlayer(position, attacker) constructor invocation, though somewhat verbose than the usual

```
CPlayer newPlayer(pos, attacker);
```

It's basically the same as saying:

```
int i = int(3);
```

Comment: Careful here. It's a "copy initialization". It's *not* an assignment.

Comment: I stand corrected, it's not an assignment; even the copy constructor isn't involved. Edit answer accordingly.

Comment: Sure, the copy ctor is (at least logically) involved. You'll notice that if you make your copy ctor private. Then, this copy initialization won't work anymore. The C++ standard requires an accessible copy ctor even when the compiler is able to optimize out the copy.

Comment: no, new allocates on the heap, your second player is on the stack thought