# What is the most preffered way to instantiate a class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, instantiation

I've been studying OOP in C++ and there are different ways to instantiate a class either through the use of the **new** keyword or the standard way (which doesn't use **new**).

Either this using **new**

```
Class *object = new Class();
```

or using the standard way

```
Class object;
```

I'm confused on when to use either ways. Can someone clarify on when to use or which is the preferred way to instantiate?

Comment: Take look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764866/4022530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this:

```
Object* o = new Object
```

you are creating a dynamic allocation, and o is a pointer. This is usually used to save memory by referencing or as an implementation for lists and trees. The memory of the pointer must be deleted using *delete* because once it is out of scope the object will still exist but you will not have access, this is called a memory leak.

In the other declaration

```
Object o; // or Object o = Object()
```

You are declaring an instance of the object, not a pointer.

A pointer contains a reference of an object, not the object itself.

So answering to your question the prefered way depends but normally you'll want to use the version without new.

Comment: Ohh! It makes sense now. Thank you for the detailed clarification!

Answer (score 0):

The **new** keyword is used to dynamically allocate memory. By using the **new** keyword, if sufficient memory is available, it initializes the memory in heap and return the address. it's then your responsibility to free memory using **delete** .

Otherwise, if new operator is not used, the object is automatically destroyed if goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I'll just avoid using new/delete to avoid memory leaks.