# How values of member variables are getting copied even though copy constructor is not getting called due to RVO in C++

Tags: c++

I am not able to understand how the values of member variables are getting copied even though the constructor is not getting called in the below program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        myclass(int a, int b)
        {
            cout << "In Constructor" << endl;
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }

        ~myclass()
        {
            cout << "In Destructor" << endl;
        }

        myclass(const myclass &obj)
        {
            cout << "In Copy Constuctor " << obj.x << " " << obj.y << endl;
            x = obj.x;
            y = obj.y;
        }

        myclass &operator=(const myclass &obj)
        {
            cout << "In Operator Overloading" << obj.x << obj.y << endl;
            x = obj.x;
            y = obj.y;

            return *this;
        }
};

int main()
{
    myclass obj1 = myclass(2, 3);
    cout << "obj1.x : " << obj1.x << "obj1.y" << obj1.y << endl;
}

Output:
In Constructor
obj1.x : 2obj1.y3
In Destructor
```

I understood that due to Return Value Optimization, copy constructor is not getting called. But I didn't understand how obj1 is getting values 2 and 3. Can any one please help me to understand this or how Return Value Optimization will work behind the scenes.

Comment: What output do you get? What do you think is called?

Comment: In your example, `myclass obj1 = myclass(2, 3);` is similar to `myclass obj1(2, 3);`

Comment: The compiler's optimizer probably determined that you're creating a single object, not two objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853700/c-object-instantiation-vs-assignment

Comment: No. This is not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values *aren't* getting copied, because they don't *need* to be copied. Instead, the values which would have been copied are initialized in place. Copy elision means that the compiler essentially turns this:

```
myclass obj1 = myclass(2, 3);
```

Into this:

```
myclass obj1(2, 3);
```

So no extra object is constructed which needs to be copied.

Note that RVO, which you've referred to, is a form of copy elision. But this specific case of copy elision is not RVO.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I understood the difference between copy elision and RVO with your answer