# constructor with assignment operator

Tags: c++, constructor

I am learning C++ and come across this question when learning the use of constructors. Consider the snippet below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { m_ = 0; cout << "default ctor called." << endl; }
    Foo(int a) { m_ = 1; cout << "int ctor called." << endl; }
    Foo(string str) { m_ = 2; cout << "str ctor called." << endl; }
    Foo(Foo& f)
    {
        cout << "copy ctor called." << endl;
        m_ = f.m_;
    }

    Foo& operator=(string str)
    {
        cout << "= operator called." << endl;
        m_ = 3;
        return *this;
    }

    int m_;
};


int main()
{
    Foo f1 = 100;
    cout << f1.m_ << endl;

    Foo f2 = "ya";
    cout << f2.m_ << endl;

    Foo f3("ha");
    cout << f3.m_ << endl;

    f1 = "hee";
    cout << f1.m_ << endl;

    Foo f4 = Foo();
    cout << f4.m_ << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I realize that

```
Foo f1 = 100;

Foo f2 = "ya";
```

actually calls the constructors as if I am doing

```
Foo f1(100);

Foo f2("ya");
```

I fail to find any relevant explanation on this. Can anyone please explain what is going on here? 
The following thread is close to mine but doesn't answer exactly my question.
[C++ Object Instantiation vs Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853700/c-object-instantiation-vs-assignment)

Comment: What does your C++ textbook have to say on the subject?

Comment: Initialization is different from assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Foo` object is constructed from value assigned to object ([implicit conversation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion))

> Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type
>   T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some
>   other type T2

where it is used in this context. Then [copy-initializtion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) initializes an object from another object (constructed via implicit conversation as mentioned before)

You can disable it (**only for this constructor**) by using `explicit` keyword.

```
explicit Foo(int a)
```

Which makes this operation

```
Foo f1 = 100;
```

illegal.

Comment: That doesn't disable copy initialisation. It disables conversion from an `int` to a `Foo`.

Comment: It doesn't directly disable copy initialization. It's just that explicit constructors are not considered for copy initialization.

Comment: Disabling copy initialisation would not allow `Foo f; Foo g = f;`, which your code does not.

Comment: Well, you have now completely re-written your answer, so these comments are moot.

Comment: Yes iam not good english speaker so you were right. We may remove these comments now. Anyway thank you.

Comment: I have apparently mixed up the concept of assignment and initialization. After using the right key word, I can find a lot more resources. Thank you very much.