# How do I return an array from a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I don't get a error message when I compile the code but I cant a proper result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Coord{
 int r;
 int c;
 };
struct CoordwValue{
 Coord C;
 char Value;
 };

CoordwValue* getNeighbors();

int main (){
 CoordwValue *k= getNeighbors();
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
  cout<<(k[i].Value);
}
CoordwValue *getNeighbors(){
 CoordwValue Neighbors[4];
 Neighbors->Value='X';
 Neighbors->C.r= 0;
 Neighbors->C.c= 1;
 (Neighbors+1)->Value='0';
 (Neighbors+1)->C.r= 1;
 (Neighbors+1)->C.c= 2;
 (Neighbors+2)->Value='1';
 (Neighbors+2)->C.r= 2;
 (Neighbors+2)->C.c= 1;
 (Neighbors+3)->Value='X';
 (Neighbors+3)->C.r= 1;
 (Neighbors+3)->C.c= 0;
 //for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
 // cout<<Neighbors[i].Value;
 return Neighbors;
 }
```

This part of the code prints X01X

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
  cout<<Neighbors[i].Value;
```

But I can't get the same result from

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
  cout<<(k[i].Value);
```

What is the problem?

Edit:

This version of the code works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


char* getNeighbors();

int main (){
    char *k= getNeighbors();
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        cout<<(*(k+i));
}
char *getNeighbors(Coord C, int r){
    char Neighbors[4];
    *Neighbors='X';
    *(Neighbors+1)='0';
    *(Neighbors+2)='1';
    *(Neighbors+3)='X'
    return Neighbors;
    }
```

Comment: What compiler? g++ gives a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return an array of four objects, you don't necessarily need to use dynamic allocation or `std::vector`.  You just need to wrap the array in a class so that you can return it.  For example:

```
struct GetNeighborsResult
{
    CoordwValue Value[4];
};

GetNeighborsResult getNeighbors();
```

Boost, TR1, and C++0x all have a container-like `array` class template that you can easily use for this purpose:

```
std::array<CoordwValue, 4> getNeighbors();
```

The advantage of using `array` is that you don't have to write a separate class for every type and number that you have, you can just use the class template.

If you do choose to return a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, **use a smart pointer** to manage the memory.  There is no reason whatsoever to not use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a pointer to a stack-allocated array.  This array will cease to exist when the function returns, so the pointer will effectively be invalid though it may still work (until you call another function, such as `cout`, when it will probably be wiped out by the new stack segment).  You probably want to say this:

```
CoordwValue *Neighbors = new CoordwValue[4];
```

Instead of this:

```
CoordwValue Neighbors[4];
```

Of course, then it's up to the calling function (`main` in this case) to properly `delete[]` the array when it is finished using it.

Comment: @redDragon: This is called undefined behavior, effectively meaning your program's behavior is unpredictable

Comment: This. And, as an additional hint, if you want to do ownership transfer, declare the return type of the `getNeighbours` function to be of type `std::auto_ptr<CoordwValue>` - safer than manually allocating the array and hoping the calle won't forget to free it, or properly implements exception handling.

Comment: @Jim: std::auto_ptr is an abomination and is (thank you very much) deprecated in C++0x. std::unique_ptr provides a superior alternative

Comment: Is there a reason to call `delete` if you expect the program to finish execution just after `new` was called? The memory is cleaned up anyway after the application terminates.

Comment: @Leonid:  Yes, yes, yes, yes, yes.  For one thing, `delete` doesn't just free memory, it destroys objects.  If you have objects that manage non-memory resources (files, registry keys, streams, sockets, synchronization objects, etc.) then this is be very, very important.  For another thing, it's _wrong_ not to clean up after yourself.

Comment: @Leonid A) if you get in the habit of not deleting when it doesn't matter, will you be as likely to remember when it does matter? B) what happens if the code is rearranged so it does matter, but the missing delete is hidden somewhere unnoticed C) what if the object's destructor performs some function (either now or in the future) that has an effect outside just the memory used by the application.

Comment: Should I use delete[]k or delete[] Neighbors?
I think delete[]k but I want to be sure :)

Comment: @redRagon:  You should do neither:  use `std::vector` or a smart pointer.

Comment: This is a "just don't do it this way" situation. Return std::string or vector<char> if you have to allocate and return in a function. In C++0x you will be able to return by r-value, i.e. "move" the memory so it doesn't have to make that copy, although with RVO will probably optimise it already. If you really want to be certain to save the copy then pass in a buffer as a parameter, ideally std::string& or std::vector<char>&

Answer (score 1):

Returned array is created on the `stack` and returned. I'd suggest to read about difference of heap and stack memory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c).

If array needs to be returned from a function you have an option of allocating memory dynamically using `new`. However, then the memory must be released with `delete` or it will result in a memory leak.

`STL` containers use dynamic memory and have overloaded `copy constructor`. Replacing array with `vector<T>` will allow you to return the values safely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a variable on the stack. The variable `Neighbors` is created in on the stack in the method `getNeighbors`. When you leave this method, the memory is destroyed, corrupting your return value.

How to fix it? Pass in an array created on the outside and fill the values in.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of a local variable. When `getNeighbors` returns, `Neighbors[4]` goes out of scope, causing all sorts of problems, including what should be a compiler warning/error.

You have a couple of options around this: first, do what cdhowie said and return a dynamically allocated array. Another is to return by value, so the return is a COPY of `Neighbors[4]`, not a pointer to it. I think the syntax for this would be something like `CoordwValue getNeighbors()[4] { .... }`

Yet another is to have the caller pass in a pre-allocated array that you fill in.

Comment: The syntax you use is correct, but the semantics you want to apply is not: A function cannot have a return type of array type (no array and no function type).