# C++ passing a pointer to static function changes value during execution

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
Node* Node::createNode(int n)
{
    Node newNode(n);
    Node *temp = &newNode;
    return temp;
}

void Node::printNode(Node* node)
{
    cout << node->data << "\t" << node->next << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Here is the main function

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Node *head = Node::createNode(10);
    Node::printNode(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem, I was expecting to print 10. Instead I get a garbage value of -858993460. I have noticed that until the point, parameter is passed into the function, it retains correct value. But inside the function printNode, the value changes. So I guess something is going wrong in the function call. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, you don't need to code printNode that way. Use `void Node::printNode(){ cout << this->data << endl; }` or `void printNode(Node *node){ cout << node->data << endl; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable. When you later use that pointer in the main function, the variable it pointed to is long gone and you enter the realm of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

You could just return the node by value:

```
Node Node::createNode(int n)
{
    Node newNode(n);
    return newNode;
}
```

Or you could allocate one dynamically and return a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c) to it, enabling scope bound resource management (aka RAII):

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> Node::createNode(int n)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(n));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to a locally scoped `Node` in `createNode`. This is a **bad thing(tm)**. When that function goes out of scope (i.e. returns), who knows what happens to what you are pointing to.

instead use one of the following:

1. copy construct (and return by value)
2. allocate on heap (`new Node`) and return (pref. using smart pointers)

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaken in the way you create the node:

```
Node* Node::createNode(int n)
{
    Node newNode(n);       // create a node on stack
    Node *temp = &newNode; // get address of the node on stack
    return temp;           // return that address
}                          // and here the node is destructed!
```

You should have allocated it in the heap via **operator new()**.

See also [Stack, Static, and Heap in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c/409072#409072) and http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/ for explainations.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a reference to a local

```
Node newNode(n);
Node *temp = &newNode;
return temp;
```

newNode goes out of scope and is overwritten by later stack contents.

Answer (score 0):

In Node::createNode() function, you are returning the address of a local variable. This is a major gaffe. The life of the Node object goes out of scope once you return from the function, it gets ejected from the stack.