# c++ allocate *new Object() to reference

Tags: c++, reference, allocation

I have a question about allocating in c++.
I have this code:

```
vector<unsigned char> &v = *new vector<unsigned char>();
```

Now the question is, is it generally a good idea to dereference the object and assigning it directly to a reference?

In my opinion, that makes it easier to use the object, because now you can just do:

```
v.push_back('a');
v[0];
```

instead of

```
v->push_back('a');
(*v)[0];
```

finally, I can do

```
delete &v;
```

to free my heap

Just because of the amount of (same) nice answers:
I know I can just use a stack-variable
but in my case, I need it on the heap!
But the question of using a heap or stack-variable is another one.

So I kept this example simple and especially did not asked if I should allocate the variable at all.

Comment: Why have it on the heap in the first place then?

Comment: Seems strange that you actually have to do this in the first place. Why do you need to "new" a vector?

Comment: You know what would be even easier? Just `vector<unsigned char> v;`.

Comment: Well it's possible, but you I doubt you could free the object the way you want to, meaning you have a memory leak. Why not simple use a pointer if you want an object on the heap?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg There's no problem freeing the object; he shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purely a stylistic issue.  None of the places I've worked
have used this convention, so it might deroute new people in
your organization, but it *is* a valid convention.

It should be part of a larger definition of when you use
pointers, and when you use references.  (And you'll find a lot
of variation in this; I've used at least three different
conventions in different firms.)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it generally a good idea to dereference the object and assigning it directly to a reference?

No, not at all.

If you don't need dynamic allocation, because the object only needs to last as long as the current scope, then make an automatic variable instead:

```
vector<unsigned char> v;
```

If you do need a dynamic object, then trying to disguise it is a good way to forget that it needs deleting. The best thing is to use a smart pointer so you don't need to remember to delete it at all; failing that, use a pointer.

Comment: What about something like `Base& obj = *(condition ? new Derived1 : new Derived2);` (with the necessary casts)?  (I suspect that the fact that you can't use a smart pointer is a valid enough reason, since it means that you have to enclose all of the following code in a `try...catch` block.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to store a heap object primarily in a reference variable, for the reason Joachim Pileborg gives in his comment. You ultimately need to delete the object, and that is best done through a pointer variable (in a reference, people will always wonder whether the actual object lives elsewhere).

Comment: `delete &v;`
actually does delete the object properly,
I tested it with valgrind and it said to me he didn't found any memory leaks
so it works and the handling is far more simple than 
`(*v)[0]`

and sometimes you have to store objects in the heap, 
think about a generator function that does some other things I omitted here to keep it simple:

`
vector<unsigned char>& gen(){
 return *new vector<unsigned char>();
}
`

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you can't delete it, but that delete &v; is confusing.

Comment: @Martinv.Löwis But why is it confusing?  Only because you've never worked in a company that used this convention, or for some more fundamental reason.  (I know it surprises me, but I'm pretty sure that that's just because I've never worked in a company which used it.)

Comment: The typical usage convention of references is that they get initialized with an object managed elsewhere. Having the reference variable own the object is a violation of that convention.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
...
{
    vector<unsigned char> v; // this allocates the vector in the stack
    v.push_back('a');
    v[0];
} 
...
```

As far as I can see there is no need to allocate the vector in the heap.

You should read about heap and stack memory:

- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)
- [Stack, Static, and Heap in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c?lq=1)