# What is reasonable indicative size when it is better to go from stack to heap?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Is

```
WCHAR bitmapPathBuffer[512]
```

ok for stack allocation? or it is better to use heap for this size? What is reasonable indicative size when it is better to go from stack to heap... all says "is depens" but our brains  need some limits to orients.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack, Static, and Heap in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c)

Comment: It is not about when to use stack or heap it is about reasonable limits

Comment: use `ulimit -a` to get your limit, if you are using linux

Comment: As Raymond Chen often says, if you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: There is no such thing as a universal one-size-fits-all reasonable limit. As is, this question cannot be generally answered as it totally depends on the target platform for your application. You might want to provide some context.

Comment: Is the function recursive?  Is it at the base of a really deep chain, or the tail, or the middle, also containing half-k blocks?  What kind of data fits in 512 bytes, a fixed buffer is often a sign of bugs nearby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to check your system's default stack size, and consider whatever use your application makes of recursion, to arrive at some reasonable threshold.

Anyway, for typical desktop PCs I'd say ~100kb was reasonable to put on the stack for function that won't be invoked recursively without any unusual considerations (I had to revise that downwards after seeing how restrictive Windows was below).  You may be able to go an order of magnitude more or less on specific systems but it's around that point you'd start to care about checking your system limits.

If you find you're doing that in many functions, you'd better think carefully about whether those functions could be called from each other, or just allocate dynamically (preferably implicitly via use of `vector`, `string` etc.) and not worry about it.

The 100kb guideline is based on [these default stack size numbers ripped from the 'net](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt):

```
platform    default size    # bits  # digits
    ===============================================================
SunOS/Solaris   8172K bytes <=39875 <=12003 (Shared Version)
Linux       8172K bytes <=62407 <=18786
Windows     1024K bytes <=10581 <=3185  (Release Version)
cygwin      2048K bytes <=3630  <=1092
```

Comment: There's a big difference between Solaris/Linux and Windows.  The maximum stack size on Solaris or Linux isn't determined at link time, but at run-time; depending on context, it's easy to wrap your program in a script which invokes `ulimit -s` beforehand.

Comment: As James says, on some systems these limits can be increased or decreased, but generally if you're writing for that environment and assume the default sizes, then if someone shrunk them severely they probably expect/want your app to bail out if there's that lower level of memory usage....

Comment: My point was more that if _you_ are writing for that environment, you can enlarge them, or ask the user to do so in the user manual.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, the answer to this question is dependent on the system on which you are running.  In order to come to a sensible answer, you need to know:

- The default stack size. *This might be different for threads other than the main thread(!), or if you're using closures or a third-party threading or coroutine library.*
- Whether the system stack is dynamically resized.  On some systems, the stack can grow automatically *up to a point*.
- On some platforms (e.g. ARM or PowerPC-based systems) there is a “red zone”.  If you are in a leaf function (one that calls no other functions), if your stack usage is less than the size of the red zone, the compiler can generate more efficient code.

As a general rule I'd agree with the other respondents that on a desktop system, 16–64KB or so is a reasonable limit, but even that depends on things like recursion depth.  Certainly, large stack frames are a code smell and should be investigated to make sure they're necessary.

In particular, it's well worth contemplating the lengths of any buffers allocated on the stack… are they *really* large enough for any conceivable input?  And are you checking that at runtime to avoid overrun?  e.g. In your example, are you *sure* that `bitmapPathBuffer` is never longer than 512 `WCHAR`s in length?  If you don't know the maximum length *for certain*, the heap may be better.  Even then, if it's an adversarial environment, you may care to put a large upper bound on it to avoid attacks involving memory exhaustion.

Comment: You're last paragraph hints as another important reason to allocate arrays dynamically: the consequences of buffer overflow.  If you use `std::vector` for the dynamic allocation, and compile with the correct options, buffer overflow will cause the program to crash with an identifiable error.  If you use local allocation, buffer overflow may change the return address of the function, leading to the execution of undesirable code.

Comment: One thing that should be mentioned is recursion: The stack size limit is for the *entire* stack, adding up all functions currently running. So if you're implementing a recursive algorithm of some sort, large stack allocations become much more dangerous much more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is really "it depends".

If you have many such variables defined, or if you do relatively large stack allocations in your function and in functions this one calls, then it is possible that you will have stack overflow.

Typical default stack size for Win32 executable is 1MB. If you allocate more than that, you are in trouble and should change largest allocations to be on heap.

I would follow simple rule - if your allocations are more than say 16 - 64KB, then allocate on heap. Otherwise, it should be ok to allocate on stack.

Answer (score 2):

Modern compilers under normal circumstances use stack size of about 1 megabyte. So 1 KB is not a problem for a simple program.

If the program is very complex, other functions in the call chain also use large portions of the stack, your current function is very deep in the call stack, etc., then you better avoid large automatic variables.

If you use recursion, then you should carefully consider how deep it can be.

If you write a function that will be used in other projects or by other people, then you never know whether it can be called in a recursive function or deep in the stack. So it's usually a good idea to avoid large automatic variables in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There's no hard limit, but you might want to consider what
happens if the allocation fails.  If allocation of a local
variable fails, your program crashes; if allocation of a dynamic
variable fails, you get (or should get) an exception.  For this
reason, I tend to use dynamic allocation (in the form of
`std::vector`) for anything over about 1K.  The fact that
`std::vector` does bounds checking (at least with the
implementations I use) when compiling without optimization is
also a plus.