# Decayed array and memory deallocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been scratching my head regarding the memory 'behavior' with arrays decayed as pointers.

I have a function where an array of structures is created in a function (without explicit memory allocation) and then passed to another function as a pointer. Said function store the pointer in a static variable.

Reading this kind of code, I would say the pointer should be invalidated at the end of the first function (since no malloc was done) yet it is not.
However, calling a free() on this pointer throws a glibc error : invalid pointer. Makes sense, since no malloc was called.

- Is there some implicit memory allocation being performed because of the decaying array ?
- Is there a way to properly free the memory after this ? I know the trivial answer would be to allocate the memory myself, I am mainly asking out of curiosity.

Edit : some dummy code as requested :

```
static structure* s_array = NULL;

void foo()
{
    structure array[5];
    bar(array); // array decaying as a pointer
}

void bar(structure* ptr)
{
    s_array = array; // pointer stored in the static, not invalidated at the end of foo()
}

void freeBar()
{
    free(s_array); // invalid pointer
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code. "Without explicit memory allocation" is not a useful way to describe a C implementation.

Comment: Sounds like the array was automatic storage duration? If so, yes, the pointer becomes invalid. Accessing it after the array's lifetime ends is undefined behavior.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c. The array has to be somwhere...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794 has a good explanation of what is happening when you try to access a local variable outside its scope.

Comment: Would love to get the reason of the downvote.

Comment: Most likely the downvote was because you hadn't posted any code.

Comment: I didn't feel like this question would require code snippet to be understood. But thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: Me neither ... since I answered it before you posted the code. Have you read my answer?

Comment: @Igor it's not static ... neither in the description nor in the code subsequently posted that matches the description. It's local, and freeing that is just as "serious".

Comment: @Jim I did, thanks. Had to wait 5 minutes to accept it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would say the pointer should be invalidated at the end of the first
>   function (since no malloc was done) yet it is not.

Yes, it is, but "invalidation" in C just means that subsequent behavior is undefined ... anything can happen, including your program appearing to work perfectly.

> However, calling a free() on this pointer throws a glibc error : invalid pointer. Makes sense, since no malloc was called.

Indeed it makes sense since malloc wasn't called. You can only free memory that was malloced; freeing memory that isn't is undefined behavior, and in this case the library was kind enough to produce a diagnostic.

> Is there some implicit memory allocation being performed because of the decaying array ?

There's no such thing as a "decaying array". Arrays aren't first class objects in C so they cannot be passed to functions ... only their addresses can. The "decay" simply consists of the name of the array being converted to a pointer to the first element of the array when used in expression context ... it's a compile-time thing.

> Is there a way to properly free the memory after this ?

The memory was "freed" at the end of the first function; nothing else need be done ... other than *not* storing its address.

Comment: Thank you. T.C. link above is also a good way to explain what is going on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794