# Destructor of class with vector of shared_ptr causes error

Tags: c++, oop, vector, smart-pointers

I have a class Animal which is base class for few different Animals and a class Herd which stores shared_prt to animals in a vector. I'm unfamiliar with smart pointers but I had to use them in my code in orded to handle inheritance. It seemed to work fine but after my code gets to the destructor of "Herd" it throws an [error](https://i.snag.gy/QlHaUN.jpg).
What's wrong with it?

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal(string _sound) :
        sound(_sound) {}
    void give_sound() {
        cout << sound << " ";
    }
    bool operator==(Animal arg) {
        return (typeid(*this).name() == typeid(arg).name());
    }
protected:
    string sound;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog() : Animal("woof") {}
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    Cat() : Animal("meow") {}
};

class Cow : public Animal {
public:
    Cow() : Animal("moo") {}
};

class Herd {
public:
    Herd() {}
    ~Herd() {
        vec.clear();
    }

    Herd operator+(Animal *arg) {
        shared_ptr<Animal> ptr(arg);
        vec.push_back(ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    void operator+=(Animal *arg) {
        shared_ptr<Animal> ptr(arg);
        vec.push_back(ptr);
    }


    void make_noise() {
        vector<shared_ptr<Animal>>::iterator v = vec.begin();
        while (v != vec.end()) {
            (*v)->give_sound();
            v++;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

private:
    vector<shared_ptr<Animal>> vec;
};

int main() {
    Herd herd;
    Dog d1, d2;
    Cat c1, c2;
    cout << "sound 1: " << endl;
    herd.make_noise();
    herd += &d1;
    herd += &c1;
    cout << "sound 2: " << endl;
    herd.make_noise();
    herd += &d2;
    herd += &c2;
    cout << "sound 3: " << endl;
    herd.make_noise();
    //herd = herd - &d1;
    //herd = herd - &d2;
    cout << "sound 4: " << endl;
    herd.make_noise();
    return 0;
}
```

edit: without vec.clear() it also crashes.

Comment: Post the code in the question.

Comment: @molbdnilo here it is

Comment: "*I'm unfamiliar with smart pointers but I had to use them in my code in orded to handle inheritance.*" I'm kind of puzzled. Smart pointers clearly won't work here, since the objects are allocated on the stack. But a regular, dumb pointer should have worked just fine. Why exactly do you think you need smart pointers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dog d1, d2;
Cat c1, c2;
```

Those objects have automatic storage duration. They aren't meant to be managed be owning smart pointers.

The use case for smart pointers is heap allocation, for example:

```
herd += new Dog;
```

Comment: How should I declare them then?

Comment: @IFeel3, you don't need to. `std::make_shared` creates an object with dynamic storage duration, and immediately hands it over to a smart pointer. You don't need to declare `d1, d2, c1, c2`

Comment: Isn't declaring Animal objects like `Dog *d = new Dog;` preffered?

Comment: @IFeel3, That will create an object with dynamic storage duration, yes. But not preferred. If your `Herd` owns the animals in it, hand them over directly. Don't keep pointers to them outside of the container (you may accidentally call `delete` on those). Note that I updated my answer to fit your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is passing the address of variables with Automatic storage duration.
See: [Stack, Static, and Heap in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c)

This is what happens in your code:

You create a variable with automatic storage duration:

```
Dog d1
```

it will be automatically destroyed after going out of the scope (in your case end of the main function)

Then, you pass it's address to a function that store this address in a SharedPtr:

```
Herd operator+(Animal *arg) {
    shared_ptr<Animal> ptr(arg);
    vec.push_back(ptr);
    return *this;
}
```

doing this you tell the shared_ptr that it is responsible for this object deletion. (In simple words destructor of shared pointer will invoke `delete Animal`)

As a result your object will be freed twice, and this is forbidden.

Instead of using raw pointers you should use:

```
operator+(shared_ptr<Animal> arg)
```

And allocate your objects in following way:

```
std::shared_ptr<Dog> d1 = std::make_shared<Dog>();
```

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong with it?

In this code you are trying to create `shared_ptr` with stack allocated object. This leads to double deletion of this object, the first one happens when stack object goes out of scope. The second one happens in `shared_ptr` destructor in `delete` operator. The second one is invalid and program crashes.

```
Herd operator+(Animal *arg) {
    shared_ptr<Animal> ptr(arg);
    vec.push_back(ptr);
    return *this;
}

void operator+=(Animal *arg) {
    shared_ptr<Animal> ptr(arg);
    vec.push_back(ptr);
}
```

Comment: More percisely the error occurs at the *first* deletion. When the standard global allocator fails to find its meta-data. The first destructor call isn't due to `delete` but automatic.

Comment: Yes, the error occurs at the first deletion of stack allocated object by `delete` operator.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious problems I can see.

The first, as others have mentioned, is that `shared_ptr` assumes the object it manages was dynamically created (with operator `new`) so releases it using operator `delete` (unless a custom deleter is provided when constructing the `shared_ptr`, which your code doesn't do.    Applying operator delete to an object with `auto` storage duration causes undefined behaviour.

The second problem - which you will eventually encounter after fixing the first - is that class `Animal` does not have a `virtual` destructor.  Even if the object is created using operator `new`, operator `delete` will cause undefined behaviour for objects of actual type derived from `Animal` (i.e. if the actual objects are of type `Cat`, `Dog`, etc).