# c++ new primary type, on stack or heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management

In c++, I know local primary types are allocated on stack, and `new` a customized class is allocated on heap.

But, what if create a the primary variable via `new`, is it allocated on heap, or still on stack?

**e.g:**

```
function void test() {
  int *pi = new int(1);
}
```

I knew there is a pointer `pi` on the function's stack.
But, what about the object it point to (aka `*pi`), is it on stack or heap?

Wondering is it similar as the primary wrapper type (e.g `Integer`) from Java.

Comment: The premise of your question shows your understanding is inaccurate. Nothing a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) can't fix.

Comment: What's a primary type?

Comment: @StoryTeller I am not a c++ programmer, just trying to improve this skill now, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I wasn't really sure exactly what you wanted, but have moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What I am trying to know is when `new` applied on a primary type in c++, is it similar as the case of primary wrapper type in Java (e.g Integer), and according to your answer, it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack, Static, and Heap in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, *two* pieces of memory needs to be allocated:

1. One is created with `new`, and is on the "heap". This is allocated at run-time.
2. The other is the storage for the actual variable `pi` itself, and as it's a local variable the compiler will most likely put it on the stack. This memory on the stack is "allocated" (or rather reserved) at compile-time.

Also note that on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits, the compiler will allocate 8 bytes on the stack for the variable, and then your program allocates 4 bytes on the heap (the size of `int` is usually 4 bytes).