# How to print a double pointer value in C

Tags: c, pointers, priority-queue, opaque-pointers

we are implementing a priority queue for generic type of datas in C. We think the assignments between pointers etc. are made right, but we don't get how to print at the end the int value of "element". Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct _pqElement{
  void** data;
  void** priority;
};

pqElement* pqElement_new(void* data, void* priority){
  pqElement* result = (pqElement*) malloc (sizeof(pqElement));
  result->data=&data;
  result->priority=&priority;
  return result;
}

static int* new_int(int value){
 int *elem=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 *elem=value;
 return elem;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  pqElement * element = pqElement_new(new_int(1), new_int(85));
  printf("%d-%d", element->data, element->priority);
}
```

Comment: "We think the assignments between pointers etc. are made right," No, they are not: `result->data=&data;` you assign the address of your local copy of the pointer. After you leave the function, this address is invalid. Use `result->data=data;` instead. Same for `priority`

Comment: Why would you want to store pointers to pointers at all? Why would you want to use a pointer (or even pointer to pointer) for the priority?

Comment: Because we don't know what type of data we are going to store in the queue. That's why in the struct we have a void** pointer to store the pointer given by "new_int". However I fixed result->data=data, but still do you know how to print out the integer value which is pointed by it?

Comment: What's wrong with a `void*` instead? It can point to any data type.

Comment: In fact, a `void*` can point at anything, but a `void**` should only point at a `void*` object, so `void*` is more general.

Comment: @Gerhardh, aschepler [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738225/how-to-print-a-double-pointer-value-in-c#comment88485090_50738225). `void*` does not point to any type.  `void*` may be insufficient to completely copy a function pointer.  It  is big enough to store  object pointers.  C lacks a universal pointer primitive.  A close construct is `union { void *vp; int (fp)(); }`.

Comment: palnic, "we don't know what type of data we are going to store in the queue" --> what do you want to do if the data does not fit in a `void*`?

Answer (score 1):

Well the code as it is does not even compile, since the `pqElement` type has never been define, but only the `_pqElement` struct has been defined.

Also you are using `%d` in the `printf`, but the parameter you are passing is `void**`, so you need to cast the value.

These changes should make the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _pqElement{
    void** data;
    void** priority;
} pqElement;

pqElement* pqElement_new(void* data, void* priority){
    static pqElement* result;
    result = (pqElement*) malloc (sizeof(pqElement));
    result->data=&data;
    result->priority=&priority;
    return result;
}

int* new_int(int value){
    static int *elem;
    elem = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *elem=value;
    return elem;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    pqElement *element = pqElement_new(new_int(1), new_int(85));
    printf("%d-%d\n", **((int**)(element->data)), **((int**)(element->priority)));
    //need to free the memory allocated with the malloc, otherwise there is a possibility of memory leakage!
}
```

This will only print the first element, but you can point to the following elements by using an offset.

NOTE: As I reported as a comment in the code, you need to free the memory allocated using the malloc, otherwise you have potential memory leakage!

Comment: The issue with using non-static addresses in `pqElement_new` which get invalid after returning is also present in your code.

Comment: Is the added `static` keyword intented to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry I actually used the static keyword the wrong way. I updated the answer. Adding the static keyword ensures that the variable is stored in the static part of the memory and not the stack. The previous answer was working but had a safety issue, since the stack variables of the function are de-referenced when the function terminates and  the pointer may be overwritten. You can find some details on memory division here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: The usage of `data` and `priority` are the problem, not `element`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two levels of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pqElement{
  void *data;
  void *priority;
};

struct pqElement* pqElement_new(void* data, void *priority)
{
  struct pqElement* result = malloc(sizeof(struct pqElement));
  result->data = data;
  result->priority = priority;
  return result;
}

static int* new_int(int value)
{
  int *elem = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *elem=value;
  return elem;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct pqElement *element = pqElement_new(new_int(1), new_int(85));
  printf("%d-%d", *(int*)element->data, *(int*)element->priority);
}
```

Finally printing the value requires to cast the pointer in a proper way, as Alexander Pane already mentioned.

Using different type for priority as well will make the queue a bit less generic. You need to provide different functions for sorting, printing,  etc.

Comment: We put "priority" as "void*" cause we also need to use the same code to implements the Prim's algorithm which have the weight as float value.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, guys.
I need the code works also with strings so I did like this:

```
static char* new_string(char* value){
  char* elem= malloc (sizeof(char));
  strcpy(elem, value);
  return elem
}
```

Printing out like this:

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
   struct pqElement *element = pqElement_new(new_string("Hello"), 85);
   printf("%s-%d", *(char*)element->data, element->priority);
 }
```

Comment: You need to allocate `strlen(value)+1` bytes. Not only 1. For printing you need to remove the leading `*`.

Comment: BTW: This is not an answer and you should not post it as an answer. Instead add a new question or extend your question.