# In C++, why should I use "new" if I can directly assign an integer to the pointer without using "new"?

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, dynamic

Assuming my pointer is not pointing to an array, how is this block:

```
int *ptr_a;

ptr_a = new int;
*ptr_a = 1;
```

different compared with:

```
int *ptr_a = 1;
```

Is there a difference in memory allocation and when would I use one over the other?

Comment: when your stack is limited is one answer. even then, using smart pointers is the way  move forward. also `int *ptr_a = 1;` more likely suppose to be just `int ptr_a = 1;`

Comment: Increase your compiler's warning/error level - live: https://godbolt.org/z/n5Ng9y

Comment: `int *ptr_a = 1;` is not a valid C++.

Comment: But since you can't directly assign an integer to the pointer, rather makes the question moot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack, Static, and Heap in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int *ptr_a = 1;`doesn't create a new int, this creates a pointer `ptr_a` and assigns a value of 1 to it, meaning that this pointer will point to the address `0x00000001`. It's not an integer. If you try to use the pointer later with `*ptr_a = 2`, you will get a segmentation fault because the pointer doesn't point to an allocated memory space (in this precise case, it points to kernel memory, which is a no-no).

A good principle nowadays is to used `std::unique_ptr<int> ptr_a = std::make_unique<int>(1)`which will allocate a new `int` with a value of `1` and deallocate the memory once `ptr_a` gets out of scope.

Comment: I'd suggest a good principle is to use `int a` if a single `int` is needed rather than mucking around with a pointer to a single dynamically allocated `int`, or a `std::unique_ptr<int>`.   If you need a arbitrary-sized collection of `int`s, use a suitable standard container such as `std::vector<int>`.