# C++ What's the difference between char a[20] = {0} and char *a= new char[20]()

Tags: c++

I write a function to return IP address in C++, as I am new to C++ so I want to make my code proficient. I knew to create a new variable needs `new`, and we need to `delete` it.

I do not know why `char *hostbuffer = new char[1024]();` is not as same as `char hostbuffer[1024]={0}`, both of them are creating a size 1024 int array, right?

```
std::string ipfunction_Client(){

    char *hostbuffer = new char[1024]();---This cannot work
    //char hostbuffer[1024]={0};---This can work
    char *IPbuffer=new char[1024];
    struct hostent *host_entry;

    gethostname(hostbuffer,sizeof(hostbuffer));

    host_entry=gethostbyname(hostbuffer);

    IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));-----This is client.cpp 230
    //delete(hostbuffer);
    return std::string(IPbuffer);
}
```

If I use the above code, the valgrind's feed back is this:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==19697==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==19697==    at 0x406624: ipfunction_Client() (client.cpp:230)
```

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c

Comment: Array is basic topic of the language, SO is not a replacement of a textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
char *hostbuffer = new char[1024]();
```

`sizeof(hostbuffer)` evaluates to the size of a pointer, not the size of the array.

When you use

```
char hostbuffer[1024]={0};
```

`sizeof(hostbuffer)` evaluates to the size of the array.

The call

```
gethostname(hostbuffer,sizeof(hostbuffer));
```

will work differently based on the declaration you use.

That's the most significant difference in your code.

If you use

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
char *hostbuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE]();

...

gethostname(hostbuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

you should not see any difference in behavior.

Comment: Using all uppercase identifiers for constants became really bad habit.

Comment: @Slava, guilty as charged.

Comment: It actually bit me once, enum from somebody else code and macro from third party C library, catching it was not pleaseant though it produced compilation error. If it would not - God help he catching the bug.

Comment: Thank you, these really help me.

Comment: @Slava, I once ran into the `class Object` from two third party libraries whose headers needed to be `#include`d in one .cpp file. Fun, fun.

Comment: @Jambako, glad I was able to help.

Comment: Name collision at least does not compile, with those pesky identifiers it is really good chance it would. That would be a disaster.