# Passing a function from another class to a function

Tags: c++

The XSetErrorHandler() function from X11 lib expects a function.

If I define a function above my main() [in main.cpp] like:

```
int catch_error(Display *disp, XErrorEvent *xe){return 0;}
```

Then I do the following:

```
XSetErrorHandler(catch_error);
```

It works.

How can I put the catch_error function in a class named WindowHandler and then pass it to XSetErrorHandler();

I tried the following:

```
WindowHandler window_handler = new WindowHandler();
XSetErrorHandler(WindowHandler::catch_error);
XSetErrorHandler(window_handler->catch_error);
XSetErrorHandler((*window_handler).catch_error);
```

Error for 1) argument of type "int (WindowHandler::*)(Display *disp, XErrorEvent *xe)" is incompatible with parameter of type "XErrorHandler"

Error for 2) and 3) A pointer to a bound function may only be used to call that fucntion

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is that defined within `WindowHandler`? Is it `static`?

Comment: @tadman It's defined like this (**not static**):
`int WindowHandler::catch_error(Display *disp, XErrorEvent *xe){
    printf("Error Happened\n");
    error_flag = 1;
    return 0;
}`

Comment: why do you want to put it into a class?

Comment: @jdigital I wanted to separate it from my main.cpp file and have it in the same class that's responsible for getting the active window and other window properties.

The WindowHandler class also uses the error_flag variable to monitor if an error happened

Comment: when the callback function is invoked, there is no object (no "this"), so it's not possible to invoke a class method or access class members. have you tried defining the method as static?

Comment: @jdigital Thanks for your input. The error does disappear when defining the function as static.

Can a static function still work if you never declared an instance of the object? Because catch_error uses the int error_flag variable, which wouldn't exist if I never created the window_handler object right?

Comment: you can use a static method even if the object has not been instantiated. static methods cannot access non-static class members. if error_flag is a class member, is will also need to be static.

Comment: @jdigital You were correct on both. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a non-static member function expects an implicit first argument, which is a pointer or a reference to the class *(in this case `WindowHandler`)*. So the signature differs from the free `catch_error` function, if we take the implicit argument into account.

I don't know how `XSetErrorHandler` is declared, but the function might accept functors: In this case, you could wrap the call to `WindowHandler::catch_error` in a lambda expression that captures a pointer to your `WindowHandler` instance.

```cpp
WindowHandler* window_handler = new WindowHandler();
XSetErrorHandler(
    [window_handler](Display *disp, XErrorEvent *xe) {
        return window_handler->catch_error(disp, xe);
    }
);
delete window_handler; // if you really must use new (why would you ever?), please also delete.
```

Here is some further reading on pointers to member functions: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

## Edit:

I just realized, that `XSetErrorHandler` does **not** accept functors, but only function pointers https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/XSetErrorHandler.html. In this case, `WindowHandler::catch_error` **must** be static. You can only treat a lambda as a function pointer, if it does not capture anything.

If you really want to capture the `error_flag` in a member of `WindowHandler`, the only option I see for you is to have one global instance of `WindowHandler` *(a so-called singleton)*. Then the static `catch_error` function can set the member of this singleton, no implicit `this` argument is required.

Note that global variables and singletons are discouraged and should be avoided if possible. There are some situations, where this is not possible. Logging and error handling are often in these scenarios.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Display {};
struct XErrorEvent {};

void XSetErrorHandler(
      int (*handler)(Display *, XErrorEvent *)
) {}

class WindowHandler 
{
private:
    // constructor is private: No other class should be allowed to construct instances
    WindowHandler() = default;

    int catch_error_impl(Display*, XErrorEvent*) {
        std::cout << "Error happened\n";
        error_flag = 1;
        return 0;
    }  

public:
    // don't copy or move a singleton
    WindowHandler(WindowHandler const&) = delete;
    WindowHandler(WindowHandler&&) = delete;

    // the global WindowHandler singleton gets instantiated the first time the get_instance_ptr function is called
    static WindowHandler* get_instance_ptr() {
        // calling new in the argument of unique_ptr ctor is ok. memory is freed when the dtor is called
        static auto handler = std::unique_ptr<WindowHandler>(new WindowHandler());
        return handler.get();
    }

    static int catch_error(Display* disp, XErrorEvent* xe) {
        return get_instance_ptr()->catch_error_impl(disp, xe);
    } 

    int error_flag {0};
};

int main()
{
    XSetErrorHandler(WindowHandler::catch_error);
    std::cout << WindowHandler::get_instance_ptr()->error_flag << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MTWcfK3bs

Comment: I thought declaring on the heap was preferrable because the stack runs out of space faster. That's why I use new and malloc.

I tried putting the lambda function in and get the following error:
no suitable conversion function from "lambda [](Display *disp, XErrorEvent *xe)->int" to "XErrorHandler" exists

Comment: Are you using C or C++? In modern C++ you allocate memory on the heap ideally using smart pointers. Regarding the lambda: I just checked that `XSetErrorHandler` does not accept functors, only function pointers. In that case, your member function MUST be static. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Note that the singleton exists on the heap, like you wanted. This only makes sense for heavyweight classes with lots of data. If the `WindowHandler` only stores an int there really is no benefit. To the contrary, you add one unnecessary indirection each time you access the instance. For a lightweight `WindowHandler` it would be preferable to create the singleton on the stack. Then the static `get_instance` method should return a reference.

Comment: _create the singleton on the stack_: more likely you mean create it as a static, which is a common pattern for singletons.

Comment: I have a lot to learn after making this post, but I'll be sure to explore each topic here to get a full understanding. Thank again all for your help!

Comment: @jdigital no, though I do create it as static, I actually meant to write "on the stack". See the whole discussion on stack and heap usage under this answer. I wanted to justify the use of a static unique_pointer, which IMHO does not make sense for this simple example.

Comment: if you create the singleton on the stack, the space is "freed" when you exit the method, so that won't work for an object that is meant to be global.

Comment: Even if it's static and you are returning a reference? Are you sure? https://godbolt.org/z/6jzncbhcP

Comment: if it's a static, then it's not created on the stack.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c/409072#409072

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the refresher. I thought static variables also existed either in the stack or on the heap. My bad.